# how to dispatch data with ajax in combination with 2 submit buttons

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple "Like", "Dislike" counterscript in which data is stored in a `.txt` file, named `counter.txt`
Now i want the data to appear with ajax but i do not succeed in it. 
How can i  make this work correct?

The piece of code with php and html:

```
<?php 
$clickcount = explode("\n", file_get_contents('counter.txt'));
foreach($clickcount as $line){
  $tmp = explode('||', $line);
  $count[trim($tmp[0])] = trim($tmp[1]);
}
?>
<button class="click-trigger" data-click-id="like">Like</button> 
<span id="like" class="click-count"><?php echo $count['like'];?></span> likes.
<br/><br/>

<button class="click-trigger" data-click-id="dislike">Dislike</button> 
<span id="dislike" class="click-count"><?php echo $count['dislike'];?>  </span> dislikes.
```

The ajax js:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

   $(document).on('click', '.click-trigger', function()
   {

      $('.click-trigger').val($(this).val());
      var data = $("data-click-id").serialize();

      $.ajax({

      type : 'POST',
      url  : 'counter.php',
      data : data,
      success :  function(data)
               {                                                
                    $(".click-count").fadeIn(500).show(function()
                    {
                        $(".click-count").html(data);

                    });                     
               }
      });
    return false;
   });   

});
```

and at least how php stores the data: `counter.php`

```
<?php 

$file = 'counter.txt'; // path to text file that stores counts
$fh = fopen($file, 'r+');
$id = $_REQUEST['id']; // posted from page
$lines = '';
while(!feof($fh)){
   $line = explode('||', fgets($fh));
   $item = trim($line[0]);
   $num = trim($line[1]);
   if(!empty($item)){
     if($item == $id){
        $num++; // increment count by 1
        echo $num;
     }
    $lines .= "$item||$num\r\n";
   }
} 
file_put_contents($file, $lines);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

The .txt file looks like this:

```
 like||36
 dislike||124
```

Comment: What do you get if you do a console.log(data) in your success? Care with the "echo $num" in your while loop, the echo in your php may cause trouble. You need a response from your php to you JS

Comment: if i put `console.log(data);` in my success, i do not get any information at all

Comment: In your php try to add the `echo 'the data you want to get in your success';` at the end of your script and in your success try a `console.log(response);` to see what you get maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click', '.click-trigger', function () {
     var data = {'id':$(this).attr('data-click-id')};
     getData(data,function (res,response) {
        $(".click-count").fadeIn(500).show(function () {
           $("#"+data['id']).html(res);
        });
     });
     return false;
  });
  function getData(data,callback) {
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'counter.php',
        data: data,
        success: callback
     });
  }
```

});

**Before Html**

```
$clickcount = explode("\n", file_get_contents('counter.txt'));
foreach ($clickcount as $line){


 if($line!=''){
  $tmp = explode('||', $line);
  $count[trim($tmp[0])] = trim($tmp[1]);}}
```

**Counter.php file**

```
$file = 'counter.txt'; // path to text file that stores counts
$fh = fopen($file, 'r+');

$id = $_REQUEST['id']; // posted from page
$lines = null;

while (!feof($fh))
{
   $line = explode('||', fgets($fh));
   $item = trim(@$line[0]);
   $num = trim(@$line[1]);
   if (!empty($item))
   {
      if ($item == $id)
      {
         $num++; // increment count by 1
         echo $num;
      }
      $lines .= "$item||$num\n";
   }
}
file_put_contents($file, $lines);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: The only problem now is when click on "like" , he shows for dislike the samee valuea as for like. Only after refresh they have different values

Comment: I editing my answer with complete working script. Still you need any help i am available.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you use html classes in js instead of unique ids

you have 2 `class="click-trigger"` and 2 `class="click-count"`  so js will not be able to determine which one deal with..

`$(".click-count").html(data);` << this wont work correctly..

so easy solution is to deal with ids for each button ex.

```
<button id="like-btn" class="click-trigger" data-click-id="like">Like</button> 
<span id="like" class="click-count"><?php echo $count['like'];?></span> likes.
```

and in js:

```
$('#like-btn').on('click', function(){
  var currentValue = parseInt($("#like").text());

  $.ajax({

  type : 'POST',
  url  : 'counter.php',
  data : data,
  success :  function(data)
         {                                                
              $("#like").fadeIn(500).show(function()
              {
                  $("#like").html(currentValue+1);
             });                     
          }
  });
});
```

and do the same for dislike..

Comment: @JackMaessen code updated! try again, and test console.log(currentValue); in success

Comment: i tried your updated code but without success unfortunately...I get no information from `console.log(currentValue);` he does not increment with 1

Comment: @JackMaessen okay i got it now, `var currentValue = parseInt($("#like").text());` try again!